# Is there a way to retrieve a device's DPI without using GDI+/WinForms "Graphics" class?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, graphics

Is it possible to get my devices DPI from c# using a native win api call?

I know how to get the dpi from a windows forms application and the current code I have is:

```
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(10, 10));

  var scaleX = g.DpiX / 96.0f;
  var scaleY = g.DpiY / 96.0f;
```

I was wondering if the is a win api call that can make things easier.

Comment: That code isn't going to do anything different than Control.CreateGraphics().  A winapi call never makes anything easier.  "My devices" isn't exactly descriptive of what kind of device you are talking about.

Comment: @HansPassant 'my devices' refers to the device that the application is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [a WMI Query to the Win32_DesktopMonitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

> PixelsPerXLogicalInch
>
> ```
> Data type: uint32
> Access type: Read-only
> Qualifiers: Units (Pixels per Logical Inch)
> ```
>
> Resolution along the x-axis (horizontal direction) of the monitor.
>
> PixelsPerYLogicalInch
>
> ```
> Data type: uint32
> Access type: Read-only
> Qualifiers: Units (Pixels per Logical Inch)
> ```
>
> Resolution along the y-axis (vertical direction) of the monitor.

You might use it similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422065/wmi-get-all-monitors-not-returning-all-monitors):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher monitorObjectSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");

foreach (ManagementObject monitor in monitorObjectSearch.Get())
{
      Debug.WriteLine(monitor["PixelsPerXLogicalInch");
      Debug.WriteLine(monitor["PixelsPerYLogicalInch");
}
```

There is also the [Windows API Route with GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I've read that there are [some issues with it on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644415/86860) so your mileage may be different.

There is also the [Direct2D GetDesktopDpi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([mentioned by Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326543/86860)), which looks like it would require doing some COM Interop calls, and may or may not be as clean and will only work Windows versions where Direct2D is available. Some [additional](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b7028fab-85f5-4788-b45f-843cd4f5f3e4/direct2d-in-c) [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Direct2D and .NET.

Comment: Seems to be less trouble to invoke a `Grahics` object IMO. Great solution however.

Comment: Are you sure about PixelsPerXLogicalInch ? On windows 10 PixelsPerXLogicalInch always returns 96 for every DPI I set.

Answer (score 0):

there is api for that, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371316(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) called getDesktopApi, but i've never used it. i assume it's as easy as doing any interop call.